# How and when to create non-unique tsdb hypertable two item indexes?

Tags: timescaledb, opentsdb

I have a table that will sort of resemble a [metadata table][1].

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sensor1 (
        datetime TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
        device_id TEXT NOT NULL,
        field_name TEXT NOT NULL,
        device_value FLOAT NOT NULL
        );
```

In this table the datetime and device_id will not be unique.

I would like to make this a hypertable and be able to make indexes out of the device_id and datetime columns (the two indexes combined will also not be unique).

My question is when and how should I make the indexes? Before or after making the hypertable?

My read query will be

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM sensor1 
        WHERE device_id = '5555' 
        AND datetime >= 'Feb 10 2024'
        AND datetime < 'Feb 20 2024';
```

or

```
SELECT device_id, 
datetime,
MAX(CASE WHEN name = '[field_name]' THEN '[device_value]' AS '[field_name]',
MAX(CASE WHEN name = '[field_name]' THEN '[device_value]' AS '[field_name]',
MAX(CASE WHEN name = '[field_name]' THEN '[device_value]' AS '[field_name]'
FROM sensor1
GROUP BY device_id, datetime
ORDER BY datetime DESC;

  [1]: https://www.timescale.com/learn/best-practices-for-time-series-metadata-tables
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to worry about the indices as if you make your primary key combining time and the device_id, it will be already creating the index for you.

https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/hypertables/hypertables-and-unique-indexes/#create-a-unique-index-on-a-hypertable